# SSL - Secure & non-secure stuff on same page

Tags: http, ssl

When I am using https on a page does the page need to include only secure items from the same server or does it need to be for secure and non-secure items regardless of that item's location?

Thanks for any help you can provide on the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try it yourself?

On you secure page, which is delivered through SSL, have an image from a non-secure URL.
Then you'll know.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that you're trying to help me solve the problem myself but I've already tried that. I already have loads of those, and as far as I can tell I don't have any other content being delivered from the same domain or IP address as the main one which *doesn't* use https:// - just a few links and javascript references. Therefore, it seems to me like all the items must be secure. Is that right?

Comment: Hi, look, I didn't exactly understand your question here in the comment, I mean, could you rephrase? Maybe bring a concrete example?